# How to replace HTML of a page using Chrome Developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

Chrome developer tools can search for elements inside HTML. Is there a way to replace all  occurrences of HTML code which is matched by some custom expression (similar to standard text editors' `Replace All` function)?

---

UPDATE:

Snippets come very handy handling text replacement:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a script to find/replace and run it in the console tab.

For a manual HTML change, you can right click on any element and pick `Edit as HTML`.

Comment: Can you give simple example of console script and how to set up it? Can I use regex in the script?

Comment: [Here is one using jQuery replace function](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RRfFr/).
[and a vanilla JS replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)